# How to compare a String to Calendar's date?

Tags: android, calendar

I am using this to read over a list of HTML items.

```java
while (postIt.hasNext()) {
    Element name = postIt.next();
    nameOf = name.text();

    String platform = postIt.next().text();

    //Get the URL
    Element url = name.select("a").first();
    urlString = url.attr("href");

    //Get the Genre of the item
    String genre = postIt.next().text();

    //Get the date
    Date = postIt.next().text();
}
```

What i would like to do is compare the Date String to that of the current date on the android device?
How would i go about doing this via Calendar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`

```
Date d = new Date(); //todays date (current time)

//set the pattern here to look like the pattern you are expecting in your 'Date' variable
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String formattedDate = sdf.format(d);
//for today the string would look like this: "2011-08-26"

boolean isToday = formattedDate.equals(Date); //your answer...
```

If you are unfamiliar with [SimpleDateFormatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), check out the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  It has a lot of helpful information for setting up your pattern.

Comment: Okay cool sounds like what i need! So where will i compare my Date that i retreive from my html to the date you described above?

Comment: Where ever it is that you need to.  The code I posted above can be put almost anywhere!

Comment: Got it! Okay so one more thing... is it possible to set the format to August 26, 2011? I didnt see it in the docs.

Comment: I would guess this: "MMMM dd, yyyy".  If that doesn't work, try adding more 'M' to the beginning.  Regardless, it shouldn't hurt to try!